# How do you make a cumulative index based on 3 factor levels

Tags: r

As the title already suggests, I want to compute a (negativity) cumulative index based on the following 3 levels:

```
head(data$sentiment)
Levels:  negative neutral positive
sentiment             : Factor w/ 4 levels "","negative",..: 3 3 3 3 3
```

Say Negative is equivalent to 3, neutral to 2 and 1 is positive. The higher the score, the more negative. I intend to make an index from 0 to 100 - 100 being the most negative. The levels carry equal weight and are a cumulation of several sentiments on a particular day. What would be the best approach?

Comment: You seem to actually have four factor levels, the first being the empty string `""`. Run `levels(data$sentiment)` to confirm. I'm guessing you want `""` to be treated like a missing value?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have missings in your factor variable as pointed out by Mikael Jagan, we need to recode first and declare missings.

x <- as.numeric(data$sentiment) - 1
x <- x[x != 0]

One option could be:

```
(mean(x, na.rm = TRUE) - 1) * 50
```

Or if you don‘t want to aggregate all values and just take what you currently have:

```
(x - 1) * 50
```

This ensures that your new score ranges from 0 to 100.

Generally, what you might look for is min/max normalization:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Rescaling_(min-max_normalization)

so in your case you could start with any aggregation, like I suggested with the mean or again take your raw values.

```
new_x <- 0 + (x - min(x)) * (100 - 0) / (max(x) - min(x))
```

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(1:3, 20, replace = TRUE)
new_x <- 0 + (x - min(x)) * (100 - 0) / (max(x) - min(x))

x
 [1] 1 3 1 2 1 3 3 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 1

new_x
 [1]   0 100   0  50   0 100 100  50  50 100 100   0   0   0  50  50  50  50 100
[20]   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R has a function `scale` for this purpose. If `x` is a numeric vector listing scores from `a` to `b` and you want scores from 0 to `M`, then you would do:

```r
scale(x, center = a, scale = (b - a) / M)
```

Before you can use `scale`, you need to coerce your factor `sentiment` to a numeric vector listing the equivalent scores, like so:

```r
set.seed(1L)
sentiment <- gl(4L, 1L, labels = c("", "negative", "neutral", "positive"))[sample(4L, size = 12L, replace = TRUE)]
sentiment
##  [1]          positive neutral           negative         
##  [7] neutral  neutral  negative negative neutral  neutral 
## Levels:  negative neutral positive
str(sentiment)
## Factor w/ 4 levels "","negative",..: 1 4 3 1 2 1 3 3 2 2 ...

scores <- c(NA, 3, 2, 1)[as.integer(sentiment)]
scores
## [1] NA  1  2 NA  3 NA  2  2  3  3  2  2
```

Note that we have assigned a missing value `NA` to the sentiment `""` appearing in your factor. Now you can do:

```r
as.double(scale(scores, center = 1, scale = (3 - 1) / 100))
## [1]  NA   0  50  NA 100  NA  50  50 100 100  50  50
```

Here, `as.double` is used only to coerce the result of `scale` (a 1-column matrix) to a vector.